# Conversion of array of characters to struct type

Tags: c

I am trying to understand how the conversion of a char array to a struct type works. I have done the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {

   int a;
   int b;
   int c;

} test;

int main()
{
    char data[20];

    strcpy(data, "text");

    test *ptr = (test*)data;

    return 0;
}
```

To try and understand what is happening I have added the following lines:

If I add the line "printf("%s", ptr)", despite the fact that there is a warning, the program output is "text".

Next, if before that line I initialize a field, say ptr->a = 1, then the output of the previous printf would be some odd characters.

I guess that after the conversion, the memory that is pointed by the -data- pointer is expanded to hold the struct fields. My problem it trying to access the data after the conversion.

So, my first question is what is happening in the memory when the above conversion is taking place?

Also how can I retrieve back the original data from the -ptr- pointer?

Comment: [Nothing whatsoever is happening in this program](https://godbolt.org/z/GMTMzn). There is no observable behaviour, and a good compiler translates it all to a no-op. After you modify it, bad things may or may not happen. If you want to discuss a modified program, please post the modified program, as opposed to a list of modifications to apply.

Comment: The C standard states: `A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting
pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise,
when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, do not do this.

Second, when you access an object, you do so with a type that tells the compiler (or other C implementation) how to interpret the bytes in memory. For example, if `x` is declared with `int x;`, then, when you use `x` in an expression such as `3*x + 4`, it tells the compiler to read the bytes of `x` from memory and interpret them as an `int`.

In `test *ptr = (test *) data;`, you tell the compiler to change the pointer to `data[0]` (because `data` is automatically converted to the address of its first element, `&data[0]`) to a pointer to a `test` structure. If this works (see below), then `ptr` points to the same bytes in memory, but, when you use `ptr` in an expression such as `*ptr` or `ptr->a`, you are telling the compiler to interpret the bytes as if they were a `test` structure (and `ptr->a` tells the compiler to go into the structure, get the bytes for member `a`, and interpret them as if they were the bytes for an `int`). The bytes in memory do not change. All that changes is how the compiler interprets them. We will look at how that works below. First, let’s see three reasons why you should not do this.

One, when you convert a pointer of type `char *` to a pointer of type `test *`, the C standard only guarantees that will work if the *alignment* is correct. Alignment is a restriction on the addresses where an object can start in memory. An array of `char` can start anywhere, so your `data` array could have any address. But, in many C implementations, an `int` must start on a multiple of four bytes, and this will force a `test` structure to have at least that alignment requirement. This means that, if `data` does not start on a multiple of four bytes, the C standard does not guarantee that `(test *) data` will produce a meaningful result or that it will not trap.

Two, although C guarantees the conversion will produce a result with some meaning if the alignment is okay, the only thing it guarantees about that result is that it can be converted back to the original type and used to access the data with that original type. It does not guarantee that the resulting pointer, of type `test *`, will behave like a pointer that points to the same place in memory. (This is the rule for pointer conversions in general. There are some specific conversions that have further guarantees. For example, any pointer to an object can be converted to a pointer to `char`, and the result is guaranteed to point to the first byte of the object.)

Three, C only guarantees that accessing objects will work if it is done through certain types. If an object is defined with one type, such as an array of `char`, and is accessed through another type, such as an `int`, the C standard does not guarantee that the program will work at all. Largely, objects can only be accessed as their original type or related *compatible* types, but there are some exceptions. One exception is that the bytes of any object can be accessed through a character type. (So you can go from `int` to `char`, but not from `char` to `int`.)

So, if you want to explore what happens when you reinterpret the bytes of `data` as if they were a `test`, how should you do it? A proper way is to copy the bytes into a `test` object, which can be done like this:

```
test x;
memcpy(&x, data, sizeof x);
```

Then you can print `x.a`, `x.b`, and `x.c` and see what the values are.

If your C implementation uses four-byte `int`, as many do, then `x.a` will contain the bytes from the string that was copied in. Those will be the bytes with the character codes for “t”, “e”, “x”, and “t”. The value you get for `x.a` will depend on what those codes are (many C implementations use ASCII codes) and the order the C implementation uses for the bytes in an `int`.

Assuming your C implementation does not insert any padding between members `a` and `b`, which is likely, then the first byte of `x.b` will be zero. However, the remaining bytes in `b` and the bytes in `c` will be *indeterminate*, because they have been copied from bytes in `data` that were never given any values. “Indeterminate” is a special word in the C standard that means the bytes might not hold fixed values at all; they might appear to vary each time you access them. In practice, C implementations will commonly use whatever values happened to be in memory at the place that was chosen for the array `data`. However, aggressive optimization by a compiler can produce other results.

> Also how can I retrieve back the original data from the -ptr- pointer?

You can convert the pointer back:

```
char *p = (char *) ptr;
```

Then `p` may be used to access the bytes as their original `char` type, with `p[0]`, `p[1]`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I should probably explain why I want to do this. The reason is that I am learning network programming and I want to create a tcp_header using a structure and then send data along with the header..

Comment: @Toni: To build a network packet generically, create an array of `unsigned char` and copy the data into it (as with `memcpy`). It is possible to do it with a properly crafted, possibly packed, data structure, but this is dependent on the C implementation.